# Conditional If not returning as expected

Tags: visual-studio-2013, conditional-statements, boolean-expression, c#-7.0, boolean-operations

```
        for (int i = 0; i < iMatrix1.Count(); i++)
        {
           if (Math.Abs(iMatrix1[i]) > 1E-20 & Math.Abs(iMatrix1[i]) < 0.0001) { oArrayList.Add(0); }
            else { oArrayList.Add(iMatrix1[i]); }
        }
```

Maybe it's just tired eyes...  But I'm not getting my expected result, here.  I'm attempting to eliminate erroneous numbers that are outside the lower bound for a given tolerance. (meaning, if they are outside of the range I'm trying to define, they need to be handled as zero)

For some reason, it's also changing numbers that are outside of this lower bound.

I'm sure this is just a silly mistake.  Please set me straight.

My return value for iMatrix[i] = -0.000000000000000055

And clearly, 0.00000000000000000001 < |-0.000000000000000055| < .00001

Again, I'm sure that this is just a silly oversight...  But it's killing me, at the moment.

Comment: try to replace & with &&

Comment: && is conditional logical.  If we only evaluate the right hand side based on the necessity after evaluating the left hand, how does that solve the issue? Logically, if the left hand isn't true, then the right hand won't be evaluated. And if the left hand is true, that still doesn't explain the discrepancy in the improper evaluation of the restriction.  Nevertheless, I did attempt this, and it did not resolve the problem...

Comment: Can you post a complete program with it's output and the expected output?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - absolutely not.  This is proprietary.  But I have narrowed it down to exactly the problem area.  If I comment this out, and return just the array value, I get the exact matrix value.  My expected output, is for the value that I posted above (in absolute brackets) to be returned as zero.  What part of my question isn't clear.  Maybe I can address it better. But assuredly, the problem is not in my input values.  I am returning the unmodified values with no issue.

Comment: So nobody else is familiar with this: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Answer (score 0):

Mhan7, if I get you correctly, you are trying to do this?

```
var a = 0.00000000000000000001;
var b = -0.000000000000000055;
var c = .00001;

Console.WriteLine($"a={c},b={b},c={c} | a < b = { a < Math.Abs(b)} | c > b = { c > Math.Abs(b)}");

if (Math.Abs(b) > a & Math.Abs(b) < c) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}
```

Does that work on your computer - I used the same conditional as you. It appears that the above verifies that your code is correct, aka returns "Hello, World", because - as you said above:

> a < Math.Abs(b) < c, or AKA 0.00000000000000000001 < |-0.000000000000000055| < .00001

Comment: Why do you have a={c} in your output line?

Comment: I misunderstood you and deleted my message. The a={c}  is the new C#6 string interpolation. It sometimes makes output easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: So things between the brackets are variables. $"a={c}" is like  "a=" + c